# Send Image From Google Sheets (Google Disk) to Telegram bot

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, telegram, google-docs, google-docs-api

I'm trying sent images chart from Google Sheets to Telegram.
I'm saving image chart to Google Disk and then send it to Telegram chat (helping this my telegram bot).

If I send Google Drive link to telegram in that way:
first try:

```
file_id_0 = "https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kvitP05ofdyT4YtHgNBdjP-sxIFQlpo7/view?usp=drivesdk";
```

This is first try result: [First Try](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMIWB.jpg) - It's bad: I want to see only image on telegram chat - without links.
[image]

On this site I found resolve this problem (sorry I'm loss the link): use Google Docs with file_id from Google Drive. File ID on link up between "/d/***file_id***/view".
To confirm this decision, I took the id of some other file on Google Drive and concatenate it:

```
file_id_2 = "1bSSzt5S9SgafeAK7D6dfRiFGECxhSuXo";
sendImage(chatId, "https://docs.google.com/uc?id=" + file_id_2);
```

Second try result: [Second Try](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFGVN.jpg) - It's perfect - what I need!
[image]

Now I'm trying to extract file_id from Google Drive file
`file.getId()`
and concatenate this Id to google docs link.

Third try result:[third try](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhqAN.jpg) - unsuccessful.
[image]
If I grab the link in debug programm and open this at browser - this opened correctly (as in second try). In my opinion link on second and third link without differences. At least they open correctly in the browser.

How should I insert this link to my function so that there are no problems?

P.S: I'm so sorry for my English. I am ready to give any explanations and I hope that the pictures helped understanding my problem.

Full Code:

```
function downloadChart2() {
  let chatId = "-xxx";
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  // Get chart and save it into your Drive
  var chart = sheet.getCharts()[0];
  var file = DriveApp.createFile(chart.getBlob());

  // Set url in one cell and resize the column 
  sheet.getRange(23, 1).setValue(file.getUrl())
  sheet.autoResizeColumn(1);
  file.setName("1234");

  // first try - successful, but bad view on Telegram
  var file_id_0 = file.getUrl();
  sendText(chatId, file_id_0);

  // second try - successful, but i grab this id on adress panel in my brouser
  var file_id_1 = "1cAdAMWFdzZFRgXiM9kbxkzrwVAGpoOIy";
  sendImage(chatId, "https://docs.google.com/uc?id=" + file_id_1);

  // third try - unsuccessful
  var file_id_2 = file.getId();
  var file_id_3 = "https://docs.google.com/uc?id=" + file_id_2; // this link correctly
  sendImage(chatId, file_id_3); // but this don't work
  }
  }

function sendImage(chatId, text, keyBoard) {

  let data = {
    method: 'post',
    payload: {
      method: 'sendMessage',
      chat_id: String(chatId),
      text: text,
      parse_mode: 'HTML',
      reply_markup: JSON.stringify(keyBoard)
    }
  }
  var caption = "Second";
   UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.telegram.org/bot" + token + "/sendPhoto?caption=" + encodeURIComponent(caption) + "&photo=" + encodeURIComponent(text) + "&chat_id=" 
   + chatId + "&parse_mode=HTML");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I saw your script, I thought that the created image file might not be publicly shared. I thought that this might be the reason for your issue. So how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var file = DriveApp.createFile(chart.getBlob());
```

#### To:

```
var file = DriveApp.createFile(chart.getBlob());
file.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE_WITH_LINK, DriveApp.Permission.VIEW);
```

#### Reference:

- [setSharing(accessType, permissionType)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#setSharing(Access,Permission))

Answer (score 0):

Link

```
var file_id_3 = "https://docs.google.com/uc?id=" + file_id_2;
```

is not direct link to image. It's redirection link.
I do this:

```
var file = DriveApp.getFileById(file_id);
file.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE_WITH_LINK, DriveApp.Permission.VIEW);
var file_uri = file.getUrl();
sendImage(chatId,file_uri);
```

It's work.